# using one variable to call a second

Tags: variables, vba

I have an number of arrays:

```
mIOSconfig = Array("  ! *** SRMS ***  ", "int *** PORT ***")
mCATOSconfig = Array("  ! *** SRMS ***  ", "set port name *** DESC *** *** PORT ***   ")
```

and I want to call these using external user input.

So assuming the user inputs "IOS" I want to use the `mIOSconfig` in future code.

So let's supose the user's input is stored in variable `x`.

```
 x="IOS"
    usedarray = "m" + x + "config"

somevarible = somefunction(usedarray)

msgbox (somevarible)
```

But this doesn't work as the `usedarray` variable is a string and this is passed to the function not the array. How can I used the created `usedarray` varible to pass the array created at the start to the function?

Cheers

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could use a collection to do what you want.  Create a Collection object and `.Add` the arrays to the collection using "IOS", "CATOS", etc. as keys to the collection.

As @Justin pointed out in his comment, what you are specifically trying to do is not supported by VBA.

Comment: Cheers, yes I have used this method before and seems the best way to go. I will be porting this to pure VB.net or c# in the future, where I might implement a database to do this as potential this could end up with many arrays each with hundrads or elements, and I assume that loading them all up in to a collection may not be the most efficient programming. But for the mean time thank you for the help as this will give me the felxible aproach that I am after.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GetOptionsByName()

    Dim opts As Object, strOpt As String
    Set opts = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'load the various alternatives
    opts.Add "IOS", Array("  ! *** SRMS ***  ", "int *** PORT ***")
    opts.Add "CATOS", Array("  ! *** SRMS ***  ", _
                            "set port name *** DESC *** *** PORT ***   ")

    strOpt = "IOS"

    Debug.Print Join(opts(strOpt), "::")


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi cheers for providing the code, like I say I have used this method for collections of strings rather than arrays. and as i say for the final version I may need a more robust method. But for this demo this will do great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one array that you populate based on input, from database or config file?

Then use same array name throughout your code?

The below I knocked up in VB.Net but can't see why not VBA. Why would you let users input free text? Why not a comboBox/list of available configs?

```
Dim myStrings As New List(Of String)
Private Enum ArrayType
    IOS = 1
    CATOS = 2
End Enum
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim theInputtedType As ArrayType

    strInput = InputBox("Enter Value", "Enter the value")

    Select Case strInput
        Case Is = "IOS"
            theInputtedType = ArrayType.IOS
        Case Is = "CATOS"
            theInputtedType = ArrayType.CATOS
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Value not recognised")
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    PopulateMyList(theInputtedType)

    For Each s As String In myStrings
        MessageBox.Show(s)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateMyList(ByVal InputtedType As ArrayType)
    Select Case InputtedType
        Case ArrayType.IOS
            'This would be a config read or DB read!!!!
            myStrings.Add("  ! *** SRMS ***  ")
            myStrings.Add("int *** PORT ***")
        Case ArrayType.CATOS
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: still have the same issue though? only part of the single array or config needs to be used depending on what the user input is. There are many ways to get around this I can use. But what I want to know is if I create a create a variable that contains the name of a second variable. how can I use this to call the second variable and not be treated as a simple string.

Comment: Not if you populate the list/array with only the values for the inputted parameter you wouldn't?

Comment: @DevilWAH -- the answer to your question is No, you cannot use the value of a string to refer to your variables in VBA.  In some other languages (like VB.NET), this is possible; it is called "reflection".

Comment: yes this is basicly how I have it now, the issues is that the configs are not defined and are already read from multiply config files, so are not consistent between runs. And can be 50+ in number. My thought was to have a multi dimensional array, with the first array being the key to the rest. using the values of this first dimension to produce a list the user can chose from. I can split the array in to only the data needed. the select case system you have suggested will not work as it is not flexible enough.